# Code doesn't build when I separate compilation and linking

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, g++

I have a file named main.cpp and I'm using a shared library that has the full path: "`/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a`" and my include directory is: "`/usr/local/include/cryptopp`".

When I try to build using this command:

```
g++ -o crypto -g main.cpp -I /usr/local/include/cryptopp /usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
```

The code builds perfectly and the executable "crypto" is created.  However when I separate the compilation and the linking like this:

```
g++ -c -g -I/usr/local/include/cryptopp -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -o crypto main.o -L/usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a
```

I get these errors:

```
/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a(algparam.o): In function `CryptoPP::CombinedNameValuePairs::~CombinedNameValuePairs()':
/home/stsadm/JJ/algparam.h:135: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a(pubkey.o): In function `CryptoPP::P1363_MGF1KDF2_Common(CryptoPP::HashTransformation&, unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, bool, unsigned int)':
/home/stsadm/JJ/pubkey.cpp:17: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a(pubkey.o): In function `CryptoPP::PK_SignatureScheme::InvalidKeyLength::~InvalidKeyLength()':
/home/stsadm/JJ/cryptlib.h:2459: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a(pubkey.o): In function `CryptoPP::PK_SignatureScheme::KeyTooShort::~KeyTooShort()':
/home/stsadm/JJ/cryptlib.h:2469: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a(pubkey.o): In function `CryptoPP::HashFilter::~HashFilter()':
/home/stsadm/JJ/filters.h:517: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
```

And I *have* to get the separated way working for unrelated reasons.  Any ideas why the separated version is giving me linking errors?

Comment: That `-L/usr/lib64` looks suspicious.

Comment: As @PeteBecker says, the `lib4` looks suspicious. Where in the original (single) g++ command line do you see anything *64*?

Comment: Don't forget to include the `-g` option in the linking line too.  That isn't part of your problem, but it will become one when you've got your problem fixed.

Comment: thank you guys, that was it!  Now...  any idea of why the inclusion of an additional (albeit, unnecessary) library directory causes issues??  Qt Creator adds it automatically to the compilation steps and I'm having a hard time removing it...

Answer (score 0):

> any idea of why the inclusion of an additional (albeit, unnecessary) library directory causes issues?

The only reason I could see is if you have `libstdc++.a` or `libstdc++.so` in `/usr/lib64`, *and* that library is corrupt in some way, or simply missing `::operator delete` for some (unexpected) reason.

To see which (non-corrupt) `libstdc++` is picked up by "regular" link, do this:

```
g++ -o crypto main.o /usr/local/lib/libcryptopp.a -Wl,-y,_ZdlPvm
```